# Textview value not incrementing on button click

Tags: android, counter, increment

Iam developing a game in which i have to increment the textview value every time a "Rematch" button is tapped
Iam saving the textview value using shared preference, it works fine.
The Problem is that "if i tapped my 5 times on button then the value is shown 5, then if i closed the app and comes again it shows 5 (so shared pref works fine) but when i tapped on rematch again it again starts the textview value from 1, although my expected result was 6 because 5 was already saved

Here is my code for oncreate method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.game);


     SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
     tValue = sp.getString("textvalue","");
     coins=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     coins.setText(tValue);
```

and on button click iam doing this

```
    count++;
    coins.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
     sedt.putString("textvalue", coins.getText().toString());
     sedt.commit();
```

Comment: You don't assign the saved value to `count`?

Comment: Sir can you help me in another problem? Iam a beginner here and stack overflow doesnot allow me to ask another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I think is that count when you start the activity again is 0. You have to make count to start from the value that is saved, this could be a way to do it
`count = Integer.valueOf(sp.getString("textValue",""))`

Comment: Sir can you help me in another problem? Iam a beginner here and stack overflow doesnot allow me to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the value of `count` instead of `tValue`. So don't do `count++` but save `tValue` as int and increment that one. Also do `setText(tValue)`. Then it will work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's because count starts again as 0,
and when u press the button it wil increment to 1.

so in your `onCreate` after you get your saved value back.
assign it to count, like:

`count = Integer.parseInt(tValue);`

Hope this will help u out.

Comment: No problem, both solutions would do the job ;) , Glad u got it fixed

Comment: Sir can you help me in another problem? Iam a beginner here and stack overflow doesnot allow me to ask another question